# Get Particular Div Or Part Using PHP Curl

Tags: php, curl

```
<?php
$url='http://yoursite.com'; // link for the site
print_r(get_data($url)); //dumps the content, you can manipulate as you wish to

/* gets the data from a URL */

function get_data($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
?>
```

The Above code is Fetching Whole Site data,How to echoa specific part of data modyfying this code..pls help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515891/how-to-use-curl-to-fetch-specific-data-from-a-website-and-then-save-it-my-databa

you have to parse the DOM data

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used: [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';


// Find all article blocks
foreach($html->find('div.article') as $article) {
    $item['title']     = $article->find('div.title', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['intro']    = $article->find('div.intro', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['details'] = $article->find('div.details', 0)->plaintext;
    $articles[] = $item;
}

// Object Oriented Way
// Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();

// Load HTML from a string
$html->load('<html><body>Hello!</body></html>');

// Load HTML from a URL 
$html->load_file('http://www.google.com/');

// Load HTML from a HTML file 
$html->load_file('test.htm');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DOMDocument::loadHTML()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) along with [`DOMXPath::query()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) to get your desired elements out of the returned HTML by your CURL request.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data); // Returned $data from CURL request

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query('*/div'); // your query here to filter out the elements you need
```

You then get a list of elements of the loaded HTML in `$elements` which match the XPath query and you can work with them.

The advantage of this method is that you don't need 3rd-party libs because `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` come built-in with each PHP >= 5.0.0 installation.

Also the [XML Path Language (XPath)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) is a standard defined by W3C for addressing XML/HTML elements.