# Which ways to create DB from the data retrieved from website(HTML)?

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I have a server and need to create the db by using data from another website.I need to update my data only 4 times per day which way and which language should I use? 
                                                                               Thank you

Comment: Since you tagged `php` and `mysql`, why not use those....?

Comment: What part of this are you having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using cURL, php. Check this links [How to use cURL to fetch specific data from a website and then save it my database using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515891/how-to-use-curl-to-fetch-specific-data-from-a-website-and-then-save-it-my-databa), hopeful it will clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, but I forgot to tell you that the content of website update continuously.Which function should i use for get the data every 4hr.