# cURL using info from mySQL, then storing the cURL'ed info

Tags: php, mysql, api, curl

I'm programming in PHP.

An article I've found useful until now was mainly about how to CURL through one site with a lot of information, but what I really need is how to cURL on multiple sites with not so much information - a few lines, as a matter of fact!

Another part is, the article focus is mainly at storing it at the FTP server in a txt file, but I have loaded around 900 addresses into mysql, and want to load them from there, and enrich the table with the information stored in the links - Which I will provided beneath!

We have some open public libraries with addresses and information about these and an API.

[Link](http://dawa.aws.dk/) to the main site:

The function I would like to use: http://dawa.aws.dk/adresser/autocomplete?q=

SQL Structure: [image]
Data example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyWbY.jpg

fx this addresse: Dornen 2 6715 Esbjerg N (called AdrName in databasen).

http://dawa.aws.dk/adresser/autocomplete?q=Dornen%202%206715%20Esbjerg%20N

This will give me the following output (which I want to store in the AdrID in the database):

```
[
{
  "tekst": "Dornen 2, Tarp, 6715 Esbjerg N",
  "adresse": {
    "id": "0a3f50b8-d085-32b8-e044-0003ba298018",
    "href": "http://dawa.aws.dk/adresser/0a3f50b8-d085-32b8-e044-0003ba298018",
    "vejnavn": "Dornen",
    "husnr": "2",
    "etage": null,
    "dør": null,
    "supplerendebynavn": "Tarp",
    "postnr": "6715",
    "postnrnavn": "Esbjerg N"
  }
}
]
```

**How to store it all in a blob, as seen in the SQL structure?**

Comment: So show the code you have already tried for updating the database.

Comment: The format you get returned is called JSON, perfectly understandable by php, so why would you dump that in a BLOB? Sorry but you're not really making a lot of sense here...

Comment: This could be done in about 10 lines of code, but i need more information to help. What data do you currently have in your DB (eg whats stored in AdrName and AdrId)? Is it enough to generate the search urls, or does the search field (the bit after `?q=`) come from somewhere else? How do you currently access your DB?

Comment: @Steve: AdrID is empty, this is where I want to insert the output into. AdrName is the address fx "Dornen 2 6715 Esbjerg N" 

And yes, it is enough. I have my list of addresses in AdrName that should be behind ?q=

I access my DB though phpmyadmin - I'm not quite sure if this is the answer to your question?

Comment: @fvu: If it was easier to do - Like I said, I'm new to cURL. Sorry if it doesn't make sense :(

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I started with the code from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2YdBrkDdn0M and modifying it to post to a database instead. I've also tried using the code from another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515891/how-to-use-curl-to-fetch-specific-data-from-a-website-and-then-save-it-my-databa

And I done some of the excercises from a book called "PHP Web Scraping" (http://www.amazon.com/Instant-PHP-Scraping-Jacob-Ward/dp/1782164766) But they all talk about one URL and taking all data from one page! :(

Comment: There are two php apis you should be focusing on: curl to retrieve the data (well explained in the manual and tons of examples online). Then, head over to json, just one call to [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) will convert that JSON text into a php variable that's easy to read and treat field by field.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a cURL request in php use this method

```
function curl_download($Url){

// is cURL installed yet?
if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
    die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
}

// OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
$ch = curl_init();

// Now set some options (most are optional)

// Set URL to download
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);

// Set a referer
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.org/yay.htm");

// User agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");

// Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Timeout in seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

// Download the given URL, and return output
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
curl_close($ch);

return $output;
}
```

And then you call it using

```
print curl_download('http://dawa.aws.dk/adresser/autocomplete?q=Melvej');
```

Or you can directly convert it jSON object

```
$jsonString=curl_download('http://dawa.aws.dk/adresser/autocomplete?q=Melvej');

var_dump(json_decode($jsonString));
```

Comment: How does this loop through my database with the addresses and save it as well ?

Answer (score 0):

The data you download is json, so you can store that in a varchar column rather than blog.
Also the site with the api does not seem bothered about http referrer, user agent etc so you can use `file_get_contents` in place of curl.

So simply get all the results from your db, iterate over them, making a call to the api, and update the appropriate row with the correct data:

```
//get all the rows from your database
$addresses = DB::exec('SELECT * FROM addresses'); //i dont know how you actually access your db, this is just an example
foreach($addresses as $address){

    $searchTerm = $address['AdrName'];
    $addressId = $address['Vid'];
    //download the json
    $apidata = file_get_contents('http://dawa.aws.dk/adresser/autocomplete?q=' . urlencode($searchTerm));
    //save back to db
    DB::exec('UPDATE addresses SET status=? WHERE id=?', [$apidata, $searchTerm]);
    //if you want to access the data, you can use json_decode:
    $data = json_decode($apidata);
    echo $data[0]->tekst; //outputs Dornen 2, Tarp, 6715 Esbjerg N 
}
```

Comment: I've tried to do your code, but some how it fails!
Code: http://mesmerize.dk/curl/index2.phps
Test site: http://mesmerize.dk/curl/index2.php

**It fails in line 20 being this:**

`$sql = ('UPDATE AdrCheck SET status="" WHERE id=""', [$apidata, $searchTerm]);`

I cant figure out if it's all because I'm stupid or tired anymore! :(

Comment: @PKPX10 http://pastebin.com/z4NLajfj Please note that mysql_* functions are depreciated. You would be better using PDO with prepared statements